# Django template not found in views

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

My views look like following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

from flights.models import Farmer
from flights.serializers import FarmerSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
import datetime


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
"""
An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
"""
def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


#view to get the details of all the farmers
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_all_farmers_details(request):

  #Fetch all the farmers from database
  results = Farmer.objects.all()
  #Serialize the obtained results
  serializer = FarmerSerializer(results, many=True)
  return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

This view returns me JSON data when accessed through api directly (i.e. hitting the url directly in the browser). When I access it through angular I get following response: `Object {data: Array[2], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`

Changing  `JSONResponse(serializer.data)` to  `return Response(serializer.data)` gives me ***TemplateNotFound*** error. However similar code is working in my another project with same settings which successfully returns JSON and in angular I get [object1, object2].

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `'rest_framework',` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` file?